# Can I access the type of a nested template C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am sure the title here could be more specific, so I encourage anybody who has a better idea to change it. In the meantime, I will try my best to be clear with the question.

I have some abstract wrapper classes like this:

```
class Attribute{
public:
    static const std::string name;
    Attribute() {
    virtual ~Attribute() {}
    virtual void calculateAttribute() = 0;
}

template <typename AttType> class TypedAttribute: public Attribute{
public:
    static const std::string name;
    TypedAttribute() {}
    virtual ~TypedAttribute() {}
    virtual void calculateAttribute() = 0; 
    AttType &value();
}
```

After that, specific attributes inherit from the `TypedAttribute`, eg:

```
class AreaAttribute : public TypedAttribute<int> {
public:
    static const std::string name = "area";
...
}

class EntropyAttribute : public TypedAttribute <double> {
public:
    static const std::string name = "area";    
...
}
```

Finally, I have a templated function which is supposed to find a maximal (originally min and max, but for the sake of brevity) attribute for a range of values, something like this:

```
template <typename TAT>
int Node::minAttribute(const std::vector <MyObject *> &items) const{
// all attributes always positive scalar values

    int minVal = -1;
    for (int i=0; i < (int)items.size(); ++i)
        int v = ((TAT *)items[i]->getAttribute(TAT::name))->value();
        if (minVal == -1 || v < minVal)
            minVal = v;

    return minVal;
}
```

With an usage example `minAttribute<AreaAttribute>(myItems);`

But, doing it this way does not allow me to know how the `TypedAttribute` is typed, and I am forced to always return an `int` value. Is there a way to access the type of `TypedAttribute` used to be able to template the return value of the function? Something like this (I know this syntax does not work):

```
template <typename TYP>
template <class TypedAttribute< TYP > TAT>
TYP minAttribute(const std::vector <MyObject *> &items) const{

    // example line:
    TYP v = ((TAT *)items[i]->getAttribute(TAT::name))->value();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typedef or using in your TypedAttribute classes would make the class available.

```
template <typename AttType>
class TypedAttribute: public Attribute
{
    public:    
    using AttributeType = AttType; 
    //can use a typedef for older versions of C++

    //...
};
```

Then to make use of this change your minAttribute function to return that type:-

```
template <typename TAT>
typename TAT::AttributeType Node::minAttribute(const std::vector <MyObject *> &items) const
{
   // can return TAT::AttributeType instead of int
   // will need a < operator than can be used with TAT::AttributeType
}
```

Comment: Really nice, I wonder how I didn't know of this before. From a purely aesthetic point of view, what is a common way of writing this shortly? As I am in fact working with `pair`s, it becomes a handful to write `std::pair<typename TAT:attribute_type, typename TAT::attribute_type>` every time...

Comment: If it's always a pair, with first and second the same type, you could do something like using ResultType = std::pair<AttType, AttType>; in the TypedAttribute template class. That'd save some of the repetition.